# Firefox mobile scales viewport inspite of meta veiwport tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I'm using this meta tag to set the viewport size on mobile browsers:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and this css to make sure that largeish images don't cause scrolling on smaller view ports:

```
img { max-width: 95%; }
```

The width of the content is not forced at any point. (The CSS uses max-width in most cases)

It works perfectly on chrome on android, but on firefox mobile, it changes the viewport size to fit the image in.

This makes pages with and without images look inconsistant - the site looks scalled down, and text is a little too small.

What can I do about this?

[This](http://nishantjr.github.io) is the website.

---

Update

As J. Prakash had said, the problem was that the total width of my page wasn't 100% of the viewport.

Since I wanted a 1em padding on my content, and use max-width to allow reflowing, I added this within my media query:

```
body, #content { width: 100%; }
#content {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is your site width is hard coded in ..px . @nishantjr

Comment: Yes it is. But the problem is not with the font size. It's that the viewport is too large.

Comment: So I think first you make width:100%; then check it.

Comment: @JPrakash the width of what?

Comment: Width of your site. @nishantjr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your viewport seems to be correct. your CSS isn't. to have the expected behavior you need to adjust your site-width to a maximum of 100% not a fixed pixel-width.

That results in a full code review and partly rebuild of your sites css (and html).

"

Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I'll give it a shot in a few hours. The meta tag you've posted would disallow users from scaling the site though?

Comment: Just checked the css, Ive not set the actual width of my content at any point - just the max- width. The css is here https://github.com/nishantjr/nishantjr.github.com/blob/source/style.css

Comment: change `#content {max-width: 800px;}`and `#body {max-width: 1100px;}` to `#content {width: 80%;}`and `#body {width: 100%;}` @nishantjr